# AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Notebook'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to run simple code that create a tab screen but i found this error

```
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Notebook'
```

and this is my code

```
from tkinter import  *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.title('Notebook Demo')
root.geometry()

rows = 0
while rows < 50:
root.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
rows += 1

nb = tk.Notebook(root)
nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=50, rowspan=49, sticky='NESW')

page1 = tk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page1, text='RDT & On-Air')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried just `Notebook`, since you already imported `*` from tk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Notebook` tab is from `ttk` class so `import tkinter.ttk as ttk` then do this `nb = ttk.Notebook(root)` instead of `nb = tk.Notebook(root)`

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=50, rowspan=49, sticky='NESW')
```